# Drupal menu edit/delete permissions module

Tags: drupal, permissions, module, menu

I created a website, I have a content manager role, and I want him to be able to rearange the menu, but I don't want him to see the edit/delete buttons in the view.

Is there anyy module for this ?

@Edit, I am talking about drupal 6

I solved the problem by overwriting the template, checking on the role and removing the operation links in the view for certain roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about something like [Menu Access](http://drupal.org/project/menu_access). When you say "see edit/delete buttons" I assume you mean you don't want him to have permissions to edit views. Also, I assume you're talking about Drupal 6.

Comment: I don't want them to edit the menu, but the user should be able to add menu items trough the page creation.

Comment: Hmmm. Then you probably need to prevent access to the menu altogether, in which case I suggest you try some combination of Taxonomy Menu (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and Taxonomy Access Control (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access). This might give you the control you want without affecting the menu.